# Is It Possible To Make a Transparent Google-Chrome Window?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, videochat

The use-case for this feature would be for a video chat application. In the application a user can share their desktop screen, and over top of that we overlay a second transparent google-chrome window. This extra layer will display annotations made by remote participants directly onto the presenter's screen, for example remote participants could write notes, circle items, or point at items with their mouse-cursor.

This sort of collaborative screen-share functionality is currently possible (sort of) with Zoom, Tandem, and Around.co, however these are all native desktop applications, not web-apps that run in a browser. I was wondering if it would be possible to build something comparable within the Chrome browser?

Comment: No, there's no such API, but you can write a separate utility and call it from your extension via `nativeMessaging`, and that utility will change the window's transparency.

Comment: Oh so if the user had a program built by us running on their computer, that program could change the window's transparency, and our chrome-extension could communicate with that native application? Thanks.